# I cannot install stan in R3.0.2

Tags: r, installation, stan

I have tried to install stan in R3.0.2 for many times according to the instrcution of Installing RStan on Windows, https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Windows#toolchain

I have download and install Rtools 30. It works well.

```
 > Sys.getenv('PATH')
 [1] "c:\\Rtools\\bin;c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Rtools\\bin;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin;C:\\GP;C:\\GP\\dll64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files\\Lenovo\\Fingerprint Manager Pro\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Lenovo;C:\\SWTOOLS\\ReadyApps;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\;C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\runtime\\win64;C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\polyspace\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\"
> system('g++ -v')
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\Rtools\GCC-46~1.3\bin\G__~1.EXE
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/rtools/gcc-46~1.3/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/lto-wrapper.exe
 Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/src/gcc/configure     --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-sysroot=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/mingw32 --prefix=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/mingw32 --with-gmp=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --with-mpfr=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --with-mpc=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-targets=all --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-libgomp --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-fully-dynamic-string --disable-nls --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --disable-win32-registry --disable-rpath --disable-werror CFLAGS='-O2 -mtune=core2 -fomit-frame-pointer' LDFLAGS=
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.3 20111208 (prerelease) (GCC) 
> system('where make')
c:\Rtools\bin\make.exe
```

But The installation of stan is always wrong.
It returns "Error 1" as following.

The first four line:

```
> Sys.setenv(MAKEFLAGS = "-j4") 
> install.packages("rstan", type = "source")
Warning: dependency ‘ggplot2’ is not available
also installing the dependency ‘RcppEigen’
```

The last several line:

```
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [RcppEigen.o] Error 1
make: *** [fastLm.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RcppEigen'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/RcppEigen'
ERROR: dependency 'RcppEigen' is not available for package 'rstan'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/rstan'
```

What is the problem?
How to install stan correctly?
I am sorry to ask for your kind help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using such an old R version?

Comment: The current version of R is [3.5.0](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/).

Comment: Thank you, Roland. I will use the new version.